# How could the FLEX ExternalInterface.available check fail but still be unavailable?

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, externalinterface

**Background:**

We have several flash objects written in **FLEX** and being rendered inside a single **HTML** page.

We are using **javascript** to communicate between the objects and perform other page related operations.

---

**Execution Flow:**

In the *creationComplete* event of the *FLEX* code of our objects we execute the following (pseudo-ish) code:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.addCallBack("initialize");
    ExternalInterface.callMethod("ready");
} else {
    Alert.show("No External Interface Available!");
}
```

Which executes the following **javascript** (psuedo-ish) code:

```
Object.prototype.ready = function(){
    //this is simplified.  More happens but all we care about is the following
    flexObject.initialize();
}
```

Which executes the follwoing **flex** (psuedo-ish) code:

```
public function initialize() {
    var asyncObject:Object = remoteService.executeMethod();
    asyncObject.addResponder(function(object:Object){
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
            ExternalInterface.callMethod("responseMethod");
        } else {
            Alert.show("ExternalInterface dissapeared!?");
        }
    });
}
```

Which *SHOULD* execute the following **javascript** (psuedo-ish) code:

```
Object.prototype.responseMethod = function() {
    alert("responded!");
}
```

**Problem:**

*Sometimes* the last javascript function outlined is never called.  When this happens none of the *error* alerts appear, the final code is just not executed but everything up to this point has executed successfully.

This happens about 1/100+ times in Chrome/Firefox
This happens about 1/10 times in IE8
This happens about 9/10 times in IE7 (full disclosure - the only machine we have to use for testing this is also much slower)

Since the problem is intermittent and becomes more apparent in slower browsers/machines my suspicion is that it is timing related.

If I stop the first **flex** 'intiailize' call from happening until I click a button in the UI instead of automatically on what is essentially 'creationComplete' everything ALWAYS works.

I may be able to solve the problem simply by introducing a 'delay' in the javascript but I *really really* don't like that ***hack***.

Comment: Try to put your call in try catch methord and see there is some thing going wrong

Comment: I'm wondering now if it has to do with adding a responder after the remote method is called.

Comment: That's a great question, I think a lot of people have pondered over it :) It does seem weird to add the responder afterwards. But it's actually correct: You can't add the responder till you have a token, and you get the token by making the service call.

Comment: Even though the service call is asynchronous, is there the possibility an exception coul be thrown during the service call and so the responder never added?

Answer (score 1):

I think @wvxvw's comment is right on the money.

In your initialize() method, it's very likely that the asyncObject variable is getting garbage collected (when the problem happens). Thus you see no errors at all.

Declare the asyncObject variable at the class level (not inside the initialize() function), and that will probably fix the issue:

```
var asyncObject:Object;

public function initialize()
{
    asyncObject = remoteService.executeMethod();
    ....
}
```

You also might want to look at using an HTTPService (or the other flex service classes) which returns an AsyncToken and gives you better handling of responses if your code makes many simultaneous requests....

Comment: This explanation seems to make sense so we've implemented a collection of async objects that clean themselves up when the response comes back. (the code in my description is overly simplified. there could be many going out at any given time so I need to keep a reference to all of them).

Since our problems have been intermittent it's difficult to know if keeping a reference to the async object has helped or not. I've upvoted the answer but for now I can't quite 'accept' it since I can't prove the problem doesn't still exist in some fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure if our implementation of the fix isn't quite right or if this didn't really solve the problem, but the issue surfaced again today :(

Comment: What is the type of the `removeService` variable in your `initialize()` method above, and does it really return just an `Object`? ... just curious. Might be useful to add a fault handler to your asyncObject, in case the service call is failing.

Comment: There is a fault handler. It is coming from spring an so without casting it is just an 'Object'